# Как запретить включать анимацию wow.js при скролле вверх?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Добрый день!
Я использую связку animate.css+wow.js. И есть такая проблема - если перезагрузить страницу в проскролленом состоянии, например, до середины, то после перезагрузки при скролле вверх wow.js также срабатывает. 
Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в проскролленой станице wow.js срабатывал только при скролле вниз, а при скролле вверх не срабатывал и все элементы были уже загружены без анимации.
Как это можно сделать? В документации Wow не нашла данной фичи.

Или посоветуйте библиотеки, аналогичные Wow.js, в которых есть такая функция.

Код подключения Wow.js

```
 initWow_scroll: function(){
    var main = this;

    var wow = new WOW(
        {
            offset:       0,          // distance to the element when triggering the animation (default is 0)
            callback:     function(box) {
                // the callback is fired every time an animation is started
                // the argument that is passed in is the DOM node being animated
            },
            scrollContainer: null // optional scroll container selector, otherwise use window
        }
    );
    wow.init();

    return main;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Исходный код в следующий раз прикладывайте. 
Пример `javascript`:

```
// Showed...
$(".revealOnScroll:not(.animated)").each(function () {
  var $this     = $(this),
      offsetTop = $this.offset().top;

  if (scrolled + win_height_padded > offsetTop) {
    if ($this.data('timeout')) {
      window.setTimeout(function(){
        $this.addClass('animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
      }, parseInt($this.data('timeout'),10));
    } else {
      $this.addClass('animated ' + $this.data('animation'));
    }
  }
});
// Hidden...
$(".revealOnScroll.animated").each(function (index) {
   var $this     = $(this),
       offsetTop = $this.offset().top;
   if (scrolled + win_height_padded < offsetTop) {
     $(this).removeClass('animated fadeInUp flipInX lightSpeedIn')
   }
});
```

Исходный пример: http://codepen.io/benske/pen/yJoqz

Comment: Добавила код выше